# Angualr2 how to get attr.data-item-code on (click)

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to get `attr.data-item-code` from `*ngFor` select option, I want to get the data attribute value when I click a button.

```
<div>
  <select>
 <option *ngFor="let x in players" [attr.data-item-code]="x.code">{{ x.name }}</option>
</select>
 <button (click)="preview()">Preview Player</button>
</div>
```

I tried something like below but the value is `null`

```
<div #dt>
  <select>
 <option *ngFor="let x in players" [attr.data-item-code]="x.code">{{ x.name }}</option>
</select>
 <button (click)="preview(dt.getAttribute('data-item-code'))">Preview Player</button>
</div>
```

Preview function: --

```
preview(code){
 console.log(code) // returns null
}
```

Is there a way to get the `x.code` when I click `preview()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel), later you can use `selectedValue` in the `preview()` function.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
   <option *ngFor="let x in players" [ngValue]="x.code">{{ x.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Note: You can use `[ngValue]="x"`, then required property can be accessed from object `selectedValue`.

Comment: @MrNew, So whats the problem

Comment: ah nvm yes -.- got confused, I can just pass `x` in the value to get the whole object.